# Why does await work and .then does not work in truffle exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, solidity, truffle

In my code, `await` works but `.then` dose not work in truffle exec.
I ran the following code in [Truffle exec](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands#exec).
This code has been simplified to highlight the problem.
↓`test1.js`

```
module.exports = async function(callback) {

  const fn = async function(i) {
    return i;
  };

  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    promises.push(fn(i));
  }

  const res = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(res);

  callback();
};
```

and, I run `test1.js` in truffle exec.

```
$ truffle exec test1.js
Using network 'development'.

[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

This result is what I expected. However, if I use `.then` instead of `await`
↓`test2.js`

```
module.exports = async function(callback) {

  const fn = async function(i) {
    return i;
  };

  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    promises.push(fn(i));
  }

  // I changed only this. 
  Promise.all(promises).then(v => console.log(v))

  callback();
};
```

This result is empty!

```
$ truffle exec test2.js
Using network 'development'.
```

At first, I thought this problem based on `module.exports`, so I tested this code.

```
const test_1 = require('./test1');
const test_2 = require('./test2');
test_1()
test_2()
```

result

```
$ node test.js 
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

From this result, I thought this problem based on not `module.exports` but truffle exec.

This is my environment.

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.3
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Why does `await` work and `.then` does not work in truffle exec?

Please forgive my poor English.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: `Promise.all().then()` is non-blocking.  So, it registers your `.then()` handler and then executes the next line of code `callback()`.    Sometime LATER, your promises all resolve and the `.then()` handler is called.  `await`, on the other hand suspends the execution of your function until the `Promise.all()` promise is resolved so `callback()` is called after the promises resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your call to "callback" inside of the promise resolution. Otherwise, "callback" gets executed before your promise is resolved.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(v => {
    console.log(v);
    callback();
});
```

Comment: And and probably also return the promise, to signify the caller when everything is finished.

Comment: Shouldn't really be using a callback when a perfectly good Promise is available to be returned.